# JavaScript - Google Maps API: Adjusting route distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm creating a cycling website, and the aim is to let the user enter a start and finish, as well as a distance, in order to create a route of that distance. This is what I've got so far:

http://kellyd52.000webhostapp.com/hexTestTest.html

(^^use the current locations and distance to see best example)

As of now, I can find an approximate distance by adding two waypoints, and making the route look like a half hexagon (This usually gives a distance within 5/10km of desired). Now, I need to adjust those waypoints slightly, so that the route's distance is more precise. This is the function I'm using to do that:

```
function adjustHex(diff, total)
{
  var diffMetres = diff * 500; //distance to compute and offset point
  var nearest = total; 
  var eightPoints = [-135,-90,-45,0,45,90,135,180]; //compass bearings

  var workOffOne = wayptsLatLngs[0]; //first waypoint of the hexagon
  var workOffTwo = wayptsLatLngs[1]; // second waypoint of the hexagon

  var tempPoint1;
  var tempPoint2;

  var bool; //boolean 

  for (var i = 0; i <eightPoints.length; i++)
  {
    for (var j = 0; j <eightPoints.length; j++) //double nested loop to find 8 different points around each waypoint
    {

      tempPoint1 = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(workOffOne, diffMetres, eightPoints[i]);

      tempPoint2 = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(workOffTwo, diffMetres, eightPoints[j]);

      checkThisHex(tempPoint1, tempPoint2,2,function(current) {
       //checkThisHex checks the distance using the temp waypoints, returns the distance 

       bool = compareHex(current, nearest); // returns true if that distance is nearer to the user's distance, than the previous distance

        if (bool == true)
        {
          document.getElementById("printInfo3").innerHTML = current;
          // ^ prints the new distance -> This works, it always prints a distance that is nearer

          nearest = current;
          fillWaypts(tempPoint1, tempPoint2); 
          //fills the waypts array, which can be accessed by any function -> Used for the directionsService.route
        }
      });
    }
  }
  return
}
```

The part that doesn't work is `fillWaypts`, even though I use it in another function, where it works perfectly. The code for that is as follows:

```
function fillWaypts(first, second)
{
  wayptsLatLngs = [];
  waypts = [];
  wayptsLatLngs[0] = first;
  wayptsLatLngs[1] = second;
  waypts.push({
    location: first,
    stopover: false
  });
  waypts.push({
    location: second,
    stopover: false
  });
  return
}
```

Is there any reason as to why `tempPoint1` and `tempPoint2` may not be getting sent correctly to `fillWaypts`?

Answer (score 0):

google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset is not a constructor.  You shouldn't be using the **new** keyword with this